# How could one implement multiplication in finite fields?

Tags: math, algebra

If F := GF(p^n) is the finite field with p^n elements, where p is a prime number and n a natural number, is there any efficient algorithm to work out the product of two elements in F?

Here are my thoughts so far:

I know that the standard construction of F is to take an irreducible polynomial f of degree n in GF(p) and then view elements of F as polynomials in the quotient GF(p)[X]/(f), and I have a feeling that this is probably already the right approach since polynomial multiplication and addition should be easy to implement, but I somehow fail to see how this can be actually done. For example, how would one choose an appropriate f, and how can I get the equivalence class of an arbitrary polynomial?

Comment: You'll probably have more luck asking this on http://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: mathoverflow is aimed at research mathematicians, this question is  on a much lower niveau. It probably only needs knowledge of stuff you learn in the third semester...i feel like i should be able answer it, but i'm just missing something obvious, and I'm very far from being a professional mathematician. I'm actually not even a mathemtician.

Comment: (continued) Aditionally, the problem here is more related to programming: mathematically it's pretty clear whats going on, I just cant convert the concept into an actually working computer program.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Math Exchange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First pick an irreducible polynomial of degree n over GF[p].  Just generate random ones, a random polynomial is [irreducible with probability ~1/n](http://www.mathreference.com/num-pfac,cirp.html).

To test your random polynomials, you'll need some code to factor polynomials over GF[p], see [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_factorization) for some algorithms.

Then your elements in GF[p^n] are just n-degree polynomials over GF[p].  Just do normal polynomial arithmetic and make sure to compute the remainder modulo your irreducible polynomial.

It's pretty easy to code up simple versions of this scheme.  You can get arbitrarily complicated in how you implement, say, the modulo operation.  See [modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation), [Montgomery multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_reduction), and multiplication using FFT.

Answer (score 3):

Whether there is an efficient algorithm to multiply elements in GF(p^n) depends on how you are representing the elements of GF(p^n).

As you say, one way is indeed to work in GF(p)(X)/(f).  Addition and multiplication is relatively straightforward here.  However, determining a suitable irreducible polynomial f is not easy - as far as I know there isn't an efficient algorithm for calculating a suitable f.

Another way is to use what are called [Zech's logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zech%27s_logarithms).  [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/htmlhelp/text287.htm) uses
pre-computed tables of them for working with small finite fields.  It is possible that [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/htm/ref/CHAP057.htm) does
too, although its documentation is less clear.

Computing with mathematical structures is often quite tricky.  You're certainly not missing anything obvious here.

Comment: Think, the Rabin Test for irreducibility in GF(p^n) is straight forward, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields#Rabin%27s_test_of_irreducibility  [with according to discussion q:=p and "g≠1" means "degree g ≠ 0"]

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your needs and on your field.

When you multiply you have to pick a generator of F<sup>x</sup>. When you are adding you have to use the fact that F is a vector space over some smaller F<sub>p<sup>m</sup></sub>. In practice what you do a lot of time is some mixed approach. E.g. if you are working over F<sub>256</sub>, take a generator X of F<sub>256</sub><sup>x</sup>, and let G be it's minimal polynomial over F<sub>16</sub>. You now have

(sum<sub>i smaller then 16</sub> a<sub>i</sub> X<sup>i</sup>)(sum<sub>j smaller then 16</sub> b<sub>j</sub> X<sup>j</sup>)= sum_k sum<sub>i+j = k</sub> a<sub>i</sub> b<sub>j</sub> X<sup>i+j</sup>

All you have to do to make multiplication efficient, is store a multipication table of F<sub>16</sub>, and (using G) construct X^m in terms of lower powers of X and elements in F<sub>16</sub>

Finanly, in the rare case where p<sup>n</sup> = 2<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup>, you get Conways field of nimbers (look in Conways "winning ways", or in Knuth's volume 4A section 7.1.3), for which there are very efficient algorithms.

Comment: Thought multiplication modulo irreducible polynomial is defined without knowing a generator.

Comment: @SamGinrich : defined - yes; efficient - not so much.

Comment: Certainly performance! Guess your approach is a "divide and conquer" method. What is the complexity?

Comment: Yes it is divide and conquer. If you have (p^n)^2=p^(2n) elements in the field, then holding the full conversion tables from the multiplicative group to the addition friendly representation costs (memory-wise) 2p^(2n). whereas doing it as I described above would cost you 2p^n memory wise, but also 3p^nlog(p^n) for performing the product with FFT. I.e. it's really a trade off. You pay with performance to save (sometime prohibitively a lot of) memory.

Answer (score 2):

[Galois Field Arithmetic Library](http://www.partow.net/projects/galois/index.html) (C++, mod 2, doesn't look like it supports other prime elements)

[LinBox](http://www.linalg.org/linbox-html/index.html) (C++)

[MPFQ](http://mpfq.gforge.inria.fr/doc/index.html) (C++)

I have no personal experience w/ these, however (have made my own primitive C++ classes for Galois fields of degree 31 or less, nothing too exotic or worth copying). Like one of the commenters mentioned, you might check [mathoverflow.net](https://mathoverflow.net/) -- just ask nicely and make sure you've done your homework first. Someone there ought to know what kinds of mathematical software is suitable for manipulation of finite fields, and it's close enough to mathoverflow's area of interest that a well-stated question should not get closed down.

Comment: It will probably be closed very fast on MO, which is aimed at graduate / pedagogical / research math.

Comment: I disagree. First of all because it's a tool that could be used by research mathematicians; secondly, I asked a question about the spiral of Theodorus and got a very courteous answer. (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3440/spiral-of-theodorus)

Answer (score 1):

Assume this is the question for an algorithm performing multiplication in finite fields, when a monic irreducible polynomial f(X) is identified (else consider [Rabin's Test for Irreducibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields#Rabin%27s_test_of_irreducibility))

You have two polynomials of degree n-1

```
A(X) = a_0 + a_1*X + a_2*X^2 + ... + a_(n-1)*X^(n-1) and
B(X) = b_0 + b_1*X + b_2*X^2 + ... + b_(n-1)*X^(n-1)
```

coefficients *a_k, b_k* are out of representatives *{0,1,...,p-1}* of *Z/pZ*.

The product is defined as

```
C(X) = A(X)*B(X) % f(X),
```

where the modulo operator "%" is the remainder of the polynomial division *A(X)*B(X) / f(X)*.

**Following is an approach with complexity O(n^2)**

1.) By distributive law the product can be decomposed to

```
  B(X) * X^(n-1) * a_(n-1)
+ B(X) * X^(n-2) * a_(n-2)
+ ...
+ B(X) * a_0
```

=

```
  (...(a_(n-1) * B(X)  * X 
   +  a_(n-2)  * B(X)) * X
   +  a_(n-3)  * B(X)) * X
   ...
   +  a_1      * B(X)) * X
   +  a_0      * B(X)
```

2.) For the %-operator is a ring homomorphism from Z/pZ[X] onto GF(p^n) it can be applied in each step of the iteration above.

```
 A(X)*B(X) % f(X) =

  (...(a_(n-1) * B(X)  * X % f(X)
   +  a_(n-2)  * B(X)) * X % f(X)
   +  a_(n-3)  * B(X)) * X % f(X)
   ...
   +  a_1      * B(X)) * X % f(X)
   +  a_0      * B(X)
```

3.) After each multiplication with *X*, i.e. a shift in the coefficient space, you have a polynomial *T_k(X)* of degree *n* with element *t_kn * X^n*. Reduction modulo *f(X)* is done by

```
T_k(X) % f(X) = T_k(X) - t_kn*f(X),
```

which is a polynomial of degree n-1.

Finally, with reduction polynomial

```
r(x) := f(x) - X^n  and

T_k(X) =: t_kn * X^n + U_(n-1)(X)

T_k(X) % f(X) = t_kn * X^n + U_(n-1)(X) - t_kn*( r(x) + X^n)
              = U_(n-1)(X) - t_kn*r(x)
```

i.e. all steps can be done with polynomials of maximum degree n-1.